# Ways to prevent TokenMismatch Exception using AJAX in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have analyze that ratio of getting Token Mismatch Error is very high. And this error getting because of some of the silly mistakes. There are many reasons developers are doing mistakes. Here are some of the examples.

1. Not sending `_token` on header.
2. Not sending `_token` on data when using ajax.
3. Not Permission on Storage Path.
4. Invalid Session Storage path.

And there many other reasons, feel free to edit this question for more more ways to prevent this type of error.

Comment: You have got answer ?

Comment: This is my answer to my question. These  are ways to prevent TokenMismatch Exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible Change - 1**

**Setup Token on Header**

Set the token on `<head>` of your `default.blade.php` view

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

Add `ajaxSetup` on the top of your script, that will be accessible to everywhere. This will set headers on each ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

---

**Set Token on `<form>` tag**

Add below function to your `<form>` tag. This function will generate a hidden field named `_token` and filled value with token

```
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Add `csrf_token()` function to your hidden `_token` in value attribute. This will generate only encrypted string.

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>`.

---

**Possible Change - 2**

**Check session storage path & Permission**

Here assume that project app url is `APP_URL=http://project.dev/ts/toys-store`

1. Set the write permission to `storage_path('framework/sessions')`
2. Check the path of your laravel project `'path' => '/ts/toys-store',`
   this path is root of your laravel project.
3. Change the name of your cookie `'cookie' => 'toys-store',`

   ```
   return [
       'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
       'lifetime' => 120,
       'expire_on_close' => false,
       'encrypt' => false,
       'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
       'connection' => null,
       'table' => 'sessions',
       'lottery' => [2, 100],
       'cookie' => 'toys-store',
       'path' => '/ts/toys-store',
       'domain' => null,
       'secure' => false,
       'http_only' => true,
   ];
   ```

---

**Possible Change - 3**

**Use `_token` field on AJAX**

There are many ways to send `_token` on AJAX call

1. Get all input field's value within `<form>` tag using `var formData = new FormData($("#cart-add")[0]);`
2. Use `$("#cart-add").serialize();` or `$("#cart-add").serializeArray();`
3. Add `_token` manually on data of AJAX. using `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` or `$('input[name="_token"]').val()`.
4. We can set as header on a particular ajax call like below code.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: "path/to/ajax",
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       dataType: "json",
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });
   ```